# Clang 3.1 on xcode 4.2 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to install clang 3.1 on xcode 4.2 (Snow Leopard)?

Answer (score 3):

You can also build and install it yourself.

[Instructions can be found here](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/INSTALL.txt).

I'm not sure if this (or the MacPorts solution... +1 to @trojanfoe) will easily be callable from Xcode though.  After moving everything from "`/Developer`" into & within the Xcode package, I'm thinking Apple is trying to keep Xcode a "walled garden" as well.

Comment: Agreed; I've never tried integrating a *third party* toolchain into Xcode. I predict problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try the [macports](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/llvm-3.1/Portfile) version.

You can also [download the binaries](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.1), if you can't be bothered to build it.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Not bugged at all mate.

Comment: I was to ask you not about the link, originally but how I can make it appear in xcode, or how I can know what to type in there for clang 3.1?