# How can I make clang-3.1 appear in the compiler list of XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

My question is somewhat tied to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277347/clang-3-1-on-xcode-4-2-snow-leopard)
I have OSX Lion, installed macports clang-3.1 but I think I do not see it appearing among Xcode compilers (which are LLVM GCC 3.1 and Apple LLVM compiler 3.0). I have XCode 4.2.

How can I make clang-3.1 appear in the compiler list of XCode?
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just install Xcode 4.5 which comes with clang 3.1?

Comment: I had originally XCode 4.3+ but it messed things up as no helps worked since it had a different architecture from XCode 4.2 which is conformant to the 4.2- versions -- at least it happened to work out for me like so. Now I don't have the time and the internet speed to loose this IDE.

Comment: @StephenChu I put you here a link about this http://www.macrumors.com/2012/02/16/apple-releases-xcode-4-3-now-offered-as-app-instead-of-installer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981599/llvmclang-support-of-c11)

It says I just have to set C++ language dialect to C++11 and and C++ standard library to libdc++.

On the other hand I also followed @StephenChu's advice and upgraded. (It went flowlessly, thx.)